# GraphQL Dataloader on non-id fields?

Tags: node.js, graphql, dataloader

We're using NodeJS (typescript) and GraphQL for our backend.
Therefore we rely heavily on dataloaders, and we get more and more field resolvers that needs to be resolved on something other than IDs.

An example is a field resolver on our User object, called "follows_me". In this case we need to make a lookup in our Follower collection, and match on the two user ids. Is this even possible to solve using dataloaders? To my understanding, dataloaders rely on only having one field to match on?

Here's some example code for context:

```
@FieldResolver(returns => Follower, { nullable: true })
async follows_me(
    @Root() user: DocumentType<User>,
    @Ctx() context: AppContext
) {
    // TODO: Use dataloader???
    return Followers.findOne({
        user_id: user._id,
        follow_user_id: context.user._id,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
The trick is to create a custom DataLoaderKey:

```
type FollowersDataLoaderKey = {
    user_id: Types.ObjectId;
    follow_user_id: Types.ObjectId;
};

export class FollowersDataLoader extends DataLoader<
    FollowersDataLoaderKey,
    CommunityFollower | undefined,
    FollowersDataLoaderKey
> {
    constructor() {
        super(keys => this.batchCunf(keys), { batch: true, cache: false });
    }

    async batchCunf(
        keys: readonly FollowersDataLoaderKey[]
    ): Promise<(CommunityFollower | undefined)[]> {
        const query = {
            $or: keys.map(k => ({
                user_id: k.user_id,
                follow_user_id: k.follow_user_id,
            })),
        };

        const followers = await CommunityFollowers.find(query);

        // Map results to keys:
        // Dataloader requires return [] to be of same length as keys[], even though keys may contain duplicates
        // Since the ${in} operator returns uniques, the mapping below is required
        // Read more at:
        const result = keys.map(k => {
            return followers.find(
                r =>
                    r.user_id.toString() === k.user_id.toString() &&
                    r.follow_user_id.toString() === k.follow_user_id.toString()
            );
        });

        return result;
    }
}
```